# Fotorama gallary don't work width: 100 % in the block display table-cell

Tags: fotorama

If I put the code of the gallery to display: table-cell block, the gallery does not update its width after reducing the width of the parent block.

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
   <div class="sidebar">
       Sidebar
   </div>
   <div class="mainbar">
       Mainbar
       <div class="fotorama" data-width="100%" data-ratio="3/2">
           <a href="1.jpg"></a>
           <a href="2.jpg"></a>
           <a href="3.jpg"></a>
           <a href="4.jpg"></a>
           <a href="5.jpg"></a>
      </div>        

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .sidebar,
    .mainbar {
        padding: 10px;
        display: table-cell;
        }
    .sidebar {
        width: 30%;
        background: #BEF781;
        }
    .mainbar {
        background: #F3F781;
        width: 70%;
        }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/o3cjqeau/6/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, adding "table-layout: fixed;" worked for me:

```
.page {
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```